# How to pass a PHP variable to a Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I am trying to load a file which is being uploaded using PHP script.
I have assigned a variable for the location of the uploaded file `$tra = basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);` and trying to give it as a input for the java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = <?php echo $tra; ?>;   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/xampp/htdocs/new/jmol/Jmol.js"></script>
```

But its showing an error 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\example.php on line 30** and line number 30 is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Could you show us more of the surrounding JS code? There is probably an extra angle bracket in there somewhere.

Comment: When you will start making things perfect, these type of error will automatically solved. Start with adding correct tags in question.

Comment: A parse error like this is usually an indication that there's something wrong _before_ the identified line.  It gave up parsing when it got to something it didn't recognize, but it didn't recognize it because of what came before.

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306314/how-to-pass-a-php-variable-to-javascript

Comment: @NikolaK.: It's not _quite_ exact.  This person is having problems with PHP syntax, entirely outside of the intended goal of emitting a value to JavaScript (which should work fine here if his other PHP code were made syntactically correct).

Comment: Hey this is the current weekly update of that ever-recurring question…

Comment: @NikolaK. = close but as David pointed out this is a syntax issue rather than "I have no clue at all".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = '<?php echo $tra; ?>';   
</script>
```

You need to enclose with '' to asign a string to a javascript variable. If you are trying to assign a number it should work without the quotes, unless there's an error in your PHP.